# in enum for loop, will it always start from the first one?

Tags: java

```
public enum A {1,2,3,4,5}  
A a = 2;  

for (A a : A.values()){
        if (true){
          return xxx.method1(a);
        }
}
return xxx.method2(a);
```

My question is in the for loop, will a start from 2 (2-5-1) or just start from 1 (1-5). And if for-loop doesn't return anything and it returns xxx.method2(a), would the a still be 2 or it already became 5?

Answer (score 2):

This code will not even compile, as you cannot declare a again inside the for.
You also cannot declare A with 1,2,3 as they digits are not accepted as identifiers.

But apart from it, iterations in enum starts with the first declared value till the last one. Values just gives an array of enums, so your loop is the same as:

```
A[] all = A.values();
for (int i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
method(all[i]);
}
```